# (T)SQL Merge Command

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, merge, ssms

I want to use the merge command to update all rows in the target which are not in the source set.

I only use two operations with an update command, but I always get "Can not insert duplicate key errors" - as I read the technet article there should not be any insert statement executed...

```
declare @stagingid as decimal = 2

MERGE SDH.dbo.SDH_ProduktPreis AS T
USING (SELECT *
        FROM Staging.mtc.SDH_Produktpreis
        WHERE Staging_ID = @stagingid) AS S
    ON S.PRPR_CPC = T.PRPR_CPC
        AND S.PRPR_Preistyp = T.PRPR_Preistyp
        AND T.PRPR_Origin = 'FromSource'
WHEN MATCHED
    AND S.PRPR_CPC = T.PRPR_CPC
    AND S.PRPR_Preistyp = T.PRPR_Preistyp
    AND S.PRPR_Preis <> T.PRPR_Preis
    AND S.PRPR_Gueltig_bis = T.PRPR_Gueltig_bis
    AND S.Staging_ID = @stagingid
        THEN UPDATE SET T.PRPR_sys_status = 6,
                        T.PRPR_Gueltig_bis = (SELECT CAST(GETDATE() as datetime)),
                        T.PRPR_sys_change_timestamp = GETDATE()
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
    AND T.PRPR_Origin= 'FromSource'
        THEN UPDATE SET T.PRPR_Gueltig_bis = (SELECT CAST(GETDATE() as datetime)),
                        T.PRPR_sys_status = 6,
                        T.PRPR_sys_change_timestamp = GETDATE();
```

If I add the "WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE" command SSMS always complain about inserting a duplicate key is not possible. (All Rows in the target has the field PRPR_Origin set, so only those get minded in the command.

From Technet:
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN 
Specifies that all rows of target_table that do not match the rows returned by  ON , and that satisfy any additional search condition, are either updated or deleted according to the  clause.

There does not stand anything from an insert command.
Does anybody has an advice for me? Where does my brain mislead me?

EDIT:
Source and target table are named alike but not the same. They are not even in the same database..

The source table is an extended version of the target with only one key: Staging_ID.
The target table has the same schema but not the Staging_ID column. In the target the PK is a combination of PRPR_CPC, PRPR_Vertriebsweg, RPR_Preistyp and PRPR_Gueltig_bis.

Some example data with PK marked yellow:

- [Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCAPf.png)
- [Target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnvLC.png)

But what I really don't get is, why my statement creates an insert with the "WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE", that behaviour does not fit to the MS Technet article.

EDIT:
For anyone to stumble upon this thread, experiencing something similar.
The Problem here was, that the merge command executes as a bulk operation. In my case this lead temporary to primary key violations, while executing the query.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever  The two tables are a live and staging by the looks of it.  Note the different databases and schemas.

Comment: Why its raising the error is because `PRPR_Gueltig_bis` is part of the key. You may not be inserting a new row, but you *are* changing entries in the index. It's that "insert" that the error is referring to.

Comment: I checked what you mentioned, and it looks promising. I did not find the culprit yet, because the mentioned duplicate key error is not really one, as the key does not exist in the target table, but I think I get the point with the behaviour. I was mislead by the duplicate key error and automatically thought it has to be an insert.